# Fractional output from integral PLL

Tags: pll, vco

Is it possible to get a fractional output from an integral output PLL? I am using [ADF4106](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4106.pdf).

Is it possible to generate 122.8MHz using this PLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether an output frequency is achievable depends on the input frequency.

Both the multiplication and the division in an "integral" PLL use fixed integer counters, so the result is that the output frequency is a fraction of the input frequency.

A "fractional" PLL has a mechanism to adjust the divider between cycles, so it will oscillate between frequencies so that the output frequency resolution seems to be finer than it actually is -- that is fine for some applications, but introduces noise for others.

Whether that PLL will work for you depends on your application's requirements and on what frequency reference you have available.